# ffmpeg - make a seemless loop

Tags: loops, ffmpeg, transition, fade

I'm trying to make a seamless loop in `ffmpeg`

The video has a length of 10 Seconds.
[This is the source](https://pixabay.com/de/videos/vollmond-ozean-mondlicht-meer-6435/)

The command I'm using is:

`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]split[body][pre]; [pre]trim=duration=1,format=yuva420p,fade=d=1: alpha=1,setpts=PTS+(9/TB)[jt]; [body]trim=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[main];[main][jt]overlay" output.mp4`

the video is looping seamlessly but my problem is, that the fade from the first video to the second is visible...

Thank you